# javafx+session+jetty

Tags: javafx, сессия, клиент-сервер, jetty

Недавно начал создавать клиент-серверное приложение (классическую игру на двоих) и решил попробовать использовать для создания клиента javafx.

Имеется класс на стороне сервера (использую Jetty). Основной метод принимает запрос с параметрами, отправляет их другому классу и выдает ответ в зависимости от полученного результата.

```
public void handle(String target,
  Request baseRequest,
  HttpServletRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response )
        throws IOException, ServletException {


    this.httpSession = request.getSession(true);
    if (this.sessionIdToSession.get(httpSession) == null) {
        userSession = new UserSession();
        this.sessionIdToSession.put(httpSession, userSession);
        //response.getWriter().println(PageGenerator.getStartPage(httpSession));
    }       
    StringBuffer url = request.getRequestURL();

    httpSession.setAttribute("URL", url);
    httpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*15); //time inactive in seconds

    // Declare response encoding and types
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");

// Declare response status code
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

// Inform jetty that this request has now been handled
baseRequest.setHandled(true);

Integer id = null;
String name = request.getParameter("userName");
System.out.println("Имя: "+name+"    ");
if (name != null) {
    id = sessionIdToSession.get(httpSession).getUserId(name);
    System.out.println("userId: "+id);
}
sessionIdToSession.get(httpSession).setUserSession(name, id);
if (id != null) {
    response.getWriter().println(PageGenerator.getPage(httpSession, sessionIdToSession.get(httpSession)));
} else {
    Address addressAS = ms.getAddressService().getAddress(AccountServiceImpl.class);
    ms.sendMessage(new MsgGetUserId(getAddress(), addressAS, name));
    response.getWriter().println(PageGenerator.getPage(httpSession, sessionIdToSession.get(httpSession)));
}
}
```

На стороне клиента пока сделал простейший класс:

```
public class RequestSender {
private static URL url;
private static URLConnection conn;
public static String sendGetRequest(String endpoint, String requestParameters)
{
    String result = null;
    if (endpoint.startsWith("http://"))
    {

        try
        {



            String urlStr = endpoint;
            if (requestParameters != null && requestParameters.length () > 0)
            {
                urlStr += "?" + requestParameters;
            }
            url = new URL(urlStr);
            conn = url.openConnection ();
            conn.connect();



            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку на форме выполняется этот метод и выводится ответ от сервера.

Проблема в том, что при каждом нажатии, сервером создается новая сессия.

Может кто-нибудь подскажет путь поиска решения данной проблемы (кусочки кода приветствуются).

Мои поиски привели меня к выводу, что нужно менять сервер (настроить сокет соединение).

Можно ли без использования соединения через сокет сделать так, чтобы сервер запоминал открытый клиент?

Теоретически, я хочу соединить функционал веб-браузера (в котором всё работает нормально) и клиента на javafx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно **на клиенте** обрабатывать установку куков сервером, так как скорее всего ваш jetty будет пытаться сохранить идентификатор сессии в JSESSIONID, соответственно, последующие запросы должны содержать это значение.  Далее, если ваша задача не разобраться в работе http (хотя все же стоило бы), то можно взять какую-нибудь готовую реализацию http-клиента, например  [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), [пример работы с cookies](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Обязательно постараюсь заполнить пробелы в знаниях.

Answer (score 0):

Выкладываю своё решение соединения через URL с использованием HttpCookie (может кому-то пригодится).

```
public class RequestSender {
    private static CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    //private static String requestParameters = "";
    static final String COOKIES_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";
    private static final String LOG_URL = "http://localhost:8080/hello";
```

`public static String sendGetRequest(String endpoint, String requestParameters) {
    //RequestSender.requestParameters = requestParameters;
    String result = null;
    if (endpoint.startsWith("http://"))
    {
        try
        {
            String urlStr = endpoint;
            if (requestParameters != null && requestParameters.length () > 0)
            {
                urlStr += "?" + requestParameters;
            }
            CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection ();

            //Put the cookie to the request
            if (cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0) {
                System.out.println(TextUtils.join(";", cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
                // While joining the Cookies, use ',' or ';' as needed. Most of the servers are using ';'
                conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",
                        TextUtils.join(";", cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
            }

            //Get the cookie from the response
            Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = conn.getHeaderFields();
            List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get(COOKIES_HEADER);
            if (cookiesHeader != null) {
                for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) {
                    cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
                }
            }

            //Send the request
            conn.connect();

            //Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}`

}